# thread-safe of ImprovedList from Java Concurrency in Practice

Tags: java, concurrency

I read Java Concurrency in Practice. It says this class is thread safe:

```
package net.jcip.examples;

import java.util.*;

import net.jcip.annotations.*;

/**
 * ImprovedList
 *
 * Implementing put-if-absent using composition
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
@ThreadSafe
public class ImprovedList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final List<T> list;

    public ImprovedList(List<T> list) { this.list = list; }

    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(T x) {
        boolean contains = list.contains(x);
        if (contains)
            list.add(x);
        return !contains;
    }

    // Plain vanilla delegation for List methods.
    // Mutative methods must be synchronized to ensure atomicity of putIfAbsent.

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return list.contains(o);
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return list.toArray();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return list.toArray(a);
    }

    public synchronized boolean add(T e) {
        return list.add(e);
    }

    public synchronized boolean remove(Object o) {
        return list.remove(o);
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return list.containsAll(c);
    }

    public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return list.addAll(c);
    }

    public synchronized boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        return list.addAll(index, c);
    }

    public synchronized boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return list.removeAll(c);
    }

    public synchronized boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return list.retainAll(c);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return list.equals(o);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return list.hashCode();
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    public T set(int index, T element) {
        return list.set(index, element);
    }

    public void add(int index, T element) {
        list.add(index, element);
    }

    public T remove(int index) {
        return list.remove(index);
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return list.indexOf(o);
    }

    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return list.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        return list.listIterator();
    }

    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        return list.listIterator(index);
    }

    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    public synchronized void clear() { list.clear(); }
}
```

I don't think so. The constructor argument `list` can be referenced in another thread. So if this `list` is not thread safe, it can be inconsistent in concurrency. if this `list` is thread safe, another thread operates it with the lock of `list`, and the thread using ImprovedList operates it with the lock of `ImprovedList` object lock, so they can still mutate it concurrently.

Who can tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: I think you're missing the bit of text right before that listing: "(Like Collections.synchronizedList and other collections wrappers, ImprovedList assumes that once a list is passed to its constructor, the client will not use the underlying list directly again, accessing it only through the ImprovedList.)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A citation from the book:

> this is guaranteed to provide thread safety so long as our class
>   holds the only outstanding reference to the underlying `List`.

So, you're right that the class cannot be called thread-safe if someone holds a reference to the same list. But you're wrong in not reading the book attentively.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. If you want to make such a list really "thread safe", then the fact that the "incoming" list is just used directly (and not copied for example) allows for changes in the context of any other object that holds a reference to that initial "incoming" list.

And beyond that; this implementation even allows for doing "hard modifications" to the list that are **not** synchronized; like

```
public T remove(int index) {
```

So - I agree with your assessment; this doesn't look exactly thread-safe. To a certain degree it is; but well, "being 90% thread safe", that is about as good as a project "being 90% done", right?!

Comment: Thanks, @GhostCat. I don't know why nobody tell the author to "correct" it or just clarify the prerequisite. So confusing.

Comment: Try sending them a mail / tweet ... or maybe, we are both just wrong; and overlook something; so you might ask those people for clarification ;-)

Comment: OK. I will invite the author to answer this and point out my possible wrongness.

Comment: To defend the authors of the book (probably the most famous concurrency specialists in the Java world): (1) the citation from the book: "this is guaranteed to provide thread safety so long as our class
holds the only outstanding reference to the underlying `List`"; (2) the non-synchronized `remove()` method is not from the book, it's @Richard's addition.

Comment: right. I also thought what I missed, considering they are really experts. And the code is from their website http://jcip.net/

Comment: Yeah, I see, it must be a typo on the site. There's no such code in the book.

Answer (score 1):

You miss an important point:

> `ImprovedList` assumes that once a list is passed to its constructor, the client will not use the underlying list directly again, accessing it only through the `ImprovedList`.

So the use case that your raise is not applicable here. `ImprovedList` is just similar to `Collections.synchronizedList(List)`, it is only a wrapper class that prevents any concurrent modifications on the underlying list using intrinsic locks nothing more so if the list provided to constructor is not accessed directly but through `ImprovedList`, it is thread-safe it is what you are supposed to understand in this case.

But generally speaking indeed, if you share the (non thread-safe) `List` provided to the constructor and you don't make a safe copy of it first (knowing that creating a safe copy of a non thread-safe List is not a thread-safe operation), it won't be thread-safe any more. However please note that sharing a non thread-safe `List` is a mistake so it is not really a real life use case.

Comment: The book says about ImprovedList that the performance penalty for the extra layer of synchronization is small because access to the underlying will always be uncontested. See footnote #7 at bottom of the of the same page that contains ImprovedList listing, which reads: "[7]The penalty will be small because the synchronization on the underlying List is guaranteed to be uncontended and therefore fast; see Chapter
11." My question is what if multiple threads are accessing ImprovedList concurrenty? How can it be uncontested then? What am I misunderstanding? Thanks.